# Angular $resource how to not send param in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, ngresource

```
function TestModel($resource, $location) {
   var port = $location.port() == 80 || $location.port() == 443 ? "" : $location.port();
   var root = $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + ':' + port + '/api';

   return $resource(root + '/ConfigTest/:action/:configurationId', { configurationId: '@configurationId', action: '@action' },
    {
        'importTests': {
            method: 'POST',
            params: { html: '@html' }
        }
    });
}
```

I have this $resource in AngularJS, importTests is my post request with the parameter html. Unfortunately AngularJS includes the html parameter in the Request URL, even though it is a post request. I need to remove this parameter from the URL, since the URL has a max-length and that could result in an error. 
So basically what I need is to modify the code above to go from

```
http://localhost:58861/api/ConfigTest/ImportHtml/1?html=%3Ctable+border%3D%220%22+cellpadding%3D%220%22+cellspacing%3D%220%22+width%3D%22244%22%3E%0A%09%3Ctbody%3E%0A%09%09%3Ctr+height%3D%2220%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+height%3D%2220%22+width%3D%22112%22%3ETest1%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+align%3D%22right%22+width%3D%22132%22%3E5000%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%09%09%3Ctr+height%3D%2220%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+height%3D%2220%22%3ETest+Leerzeichen%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+align%3D%22right%22%3E6000%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%09%09%3Ctr+height%3D%2220%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+height%3D%2220%22%3ETest2%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+align%3D%22right%22%3E7000%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%09%09%3Ctr+height%3D%2220%22%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+height%3D%2220%22%3ETest3%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%09%3Ctd+align%3D%22right%22%3E8000%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%09%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A
```

this url to this one:
    http://localhost:58861/api/ConfigTest/ImportHtml/1

so that the html param is only sent in the body.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to send the html as a parameter, then you shouldn't specify it as a parameter...

```
testModel.html = '<html goes here>';
testModel.$importTests()
```

Comment: If I call it from the service like this?   `TestModel.html = html;
     TestModel.importTests({ configurationId: configurationId, action: 'ImportHtml' })`  
and the model like this?
            `'importTests': {
                method: 'POST'
            }` ... Like this the param is not in the body neither though